# How to customize the color of oj-button?

Tags: oracle-jet

I have a problem with customizing the color of one button defined by oj-button:

```
<div id='buttons-container'>
       <oj-button id='in'
       style="background-color: #670067;">My Button</oj-button>
</div>
```

What I want is to change the color of the button but it did not work.

Do we have any simple way to change the color of oj-button?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying won't work; there's no easy way to change the colors of OJET buttons.

OJET gives you 2 options:

1. Use the `primary` and `confirm` classes to get blue and green colors. [Demo](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=buttonStyling&demo=altcolors).
2. Create your own theme using their Themebuilder tool. You have a lot of freedom here to change the colors, dimensions, fonts, shadows etc. But it's a lot of work if you just want to change the color of 1 button.

Themebuilder (Instructions available in the top right tab, reload page if nothing shows after a few seconds): http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/public_samples/JET-Theme-Builder/public_html/index.html?viewer=true

Comment: Thanks to Ray, got it now.

Comment: This isn't strictly true -- JET has provided a SASS mixin for customising button colours since at least v5: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=buttonStyling&demo=customcolors

Answer (score 0):

Referer this [demo](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=buttonStyling&demo=customcolors)

Create a CSS class with the colors you like and apply to any JET Button.

Answer (score 0):

JET provides a SASS mixin (though you don't have to use it) for overriding button colours, see the cookbook example here: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=buttonStyling&demo=customcolors